# Regular Expression - how do I loop through exec results

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

In the following code the results are getting logged as expected.
I now want to loop through the individual items of the match in a loop but need help. match.split fails because of a null error TIA

```
var match;
var precedents=[];  
while((match=exp.exec(text))) {
    Logger.log(match[0]);
   }
var matchArray=match.split();  

  if(matchArray.length>0){
      for(i==0; i<matchArray.length;i++){
         Logger.log(i);
         precedents[i].push(matchArray[i]);
         Logger.log(precedents[i]);
      }
  }
```

Comment: The assignment operator in this expression `for(i==0; i<matchArray.length;i++)` should be written like this `for(var i=0; i<matchArray.length;i++)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Re your first comment it seems one = is correct